# Excel - conditionally format cell based on whether it is TRUE or FALSE

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a column with this formula `=F9>=G9` (each cell refers to other cells on the same row).  I would like to when a cell says TRUE, I would like to change the text color but I can't figure out how to do so.  I've tried creating a conditional formating rule with `=TRUE` and `=1` but nothing happens.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like the following:

1. Select the cells that should be formatted.
2. Create a new formatting rule
3. On "Select a Rule Type", select "Format only cells that contain"
4. On "Format only cells with", select `equal to` and set it to `TRUE`. Choose the color and font under "Format".

[image]